# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Storage is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I use docsite to generate markdown documents, soucecode... to html pages. Now I want to add a valine (this is a feature of comment box. For details, see `valine.js.org`) plugin. I use node v10.9.0.
Here is the file I add code to:

```
import React from 'react';
window.AV = require('leancloud-storage');
import Valine from 'valine';

class Footer extends Language {

  render() {
    new Valine({
            el: '#vcomments',
            appId: '1',
            appKey: '1'
        });
    return (
      <footer className="footer-container">
        <div className="footer-body">
          <div id="vcomments"></div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    );
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io>npm run start

> site@0.0.1 start C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io
> docsite start

(node:28140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Storage is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_valine@1.3.10@valine\dist\Valine.min.js:12:5096)
    at t (C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_valine@1.3.10@valine\dist\Valine.min.js:7:316)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_valine@1.3.10@valine\dist\Valine.min.js:12:73397)
    at t (C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_valine@1.3.10@valine\dist\Valine.min.js:7:316)
    at C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_valine@1.3.10@valine\dist\Valine.min.js:7:699
    at C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_valine@1.3.10@valine\dist\Valine.min.js:7:709
    at C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_valine@1.3.10@valine\dist\Valine.min.js:7:81
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_valine@1.3.10@valine\dist\Valine.min.js:7:193)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\work\wuhan2020.github.io\node_modules\_pirates@4.0.1@pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
(node:28140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ran `npm install` before `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

The valine team has confirmed that there's something wrong with valine itself.